# How to loop though elements based on part of the dom name

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I want to hide all the elements on the page that end in _dropMenu via javascript...so this is what i have

```
window.onload = function() {
  hideNav();
};

    function hideNav(){
      myArray = element("_dropMenu");// this is what need changing 
      for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
      {
         i.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }
```

This is obviously wrong but how do I first get all the elements on the page that end with _dropMenu then loop through them and set them to hidden... I would prefer javascript since I only have prototype on the page but if I need to add jquery I will...

Comment: Do the elements have to end with _dropMenu or could you change your markup to just add a _dropMenu class? Only reason I ask is because this would make it alot easier to accomplish what you need to.

Comment: Is it the element id's that end in '_dropMenu'?

Comment: i cant change it....yes i think that would make it easier but i cant

Comment: It's pretty easy with Jquery `$('[id$="_dropMenu"]').hide()`

Comment: it didnt fail...i was having a conflict with prototype...fixed when i did jquery.noConflict

Comment: Make sure that you are using Jquery.. v1+ it cannot fail.. if are intending to hide all elements with **id ending** with _dropMenu

Comment: I flinch when I think of all the sites with the whole jQuery library added just to allow for one command. **Especially** when there is already another library present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery has a selector for finding elements that have an attribute that ends with a given string:

```
$('[id$="_dropMenu]')
```

This will be faster if you can narrow it by an element type (e.g. if all the elements you care about are divs, or some such) but will work as is.

Behind the scenes, jquery is just looping through a given set of elements, and checking whether `element["id"].substring(element["id"].length-"_dropMenu".length)==="_dropMenu"`.

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing out the Prototype is very similar to jQuery in this case:

```
$$('[id$="_dropMenu"]').invoke('hide');
```

Kudos [Jishnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546779/jishnu) & [JacobM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237/jacobm) for getting the selector first.